# How can I transfer windows partitions to ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, windows-10

I have an Asus laptop and it had windows 10 by default and it has 512 GB SSD. I shrinked about 60 GB from a windows drive and I formatted it as unallocated partition. I installed Ubuntu on that 60 GB. Now I want to change the partitions again and allocate a bigger size to ubuntu. Now I have about 200 GB of unused memory on windows and need more space on ubuntu. Note that I do not want to mount them in read-only mode. Is there a solution to do that?

EDIT: I am dual-booting now and I want to have both windows and ubuntu on my laptop. But the partition allocated to linux is only 60 GB out of 512 GB of SSD. I want it to be more. [[gparted]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXcYu.png)[Screenshot link is attached.]

EDIT: **I turned off device encryption** in windows and now I can access windows drives and files from linux. But they are mounted in read-only mode and I can not create files, etc. How can I now access them (ex. only one drive), like the main ubuntu drive?
[image: gparted now]

Comment: this user is asking the case in which there is not windows on the laptop anymore. i want to do the resize still on dual-boot mode

Comment: It doesn't matter if Windows is there or not.

Comment: It's slightly unclear... is Windows still installed? Are you dual-booting? Do you wish to move partition space from a Windows NTFS partition to increase the Ubuntu partition? Edit your question and show me a screenshot of `gparted`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema thanks to your attention. I added information.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Unfortunately your disk is protected by bitlocker. I don't know how to do what would normally be a very easy operation, when bitlocker is engaged. Sorry.

Comment: I recommend you to take it to do it in person with an experience technician, as this will need a `very situation specific` answer, which I don't think anyone will be able to answer to the point, as a loosy goosy answer will mess up your computer, and possibly lead to data loss. And whenever you solve this problem, please add an answer yourself, this will help other people facing this problem.

Comment: @heynnema could you please help me according my new edit?

Comment: What's on p4 and p5? Can either of these be deleted, or reisized? Can p5 be deleted and that space be added to p7? If so, I can write you instructions.

Comment: @heynnema I do not want to touch p4. Its drive E on windows and I have data on it. But I think its good to add all free 90 GB of p5 to ubuntu.

Comment: Ok. They've marked your question as a duplicate, which I think is wrong, so I edited your question, and asked that it be reopened to answers. Keep an eye on it, and if/when it's reopened, ping me in a comment and I can come back and write an answer for you. If it doesn't get reopened, I'll instruct you further on writing a question that won't get marked.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to boot into Windows and shut down the system. Select Ubuntu kernel from the grub menu to boot into Ubuntu afterwards. Open file manager after login, from the left pane, find the partition you want to mount under devices and click. It should be mounted and it will show on main pane

Comment: Can you explain this solution more clearly or provide a link? I am somehow a newbie and i am afraid of data loss or hurting my laptop hard drives. Are you sure this solution works?